# numpy: idiomatic way to map a function over image channels

Tags: python, numpy

Given a numpy array of shape `(h, w, c)`, i.e. an image with a certain height, width and number of channels, and a function which takes `c` input arguments and produces `c + k` output arguments, how can I map this function over the array to produce an output array of shape `(h, w, c + k)` in which each "pixel" in the input image is replaced by the function output given the channel values at that pixel.

As an example, I'd like to do something like the following (generalized to more complicated functions):

```
a = np.ones((10, 10, 3))

def f(r, b, g):
    return r, g, b, r + g + b

# TODO: map f over a resulting in np.dstack((a, np.full((10, 10), 3)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for `apply_along_axis`:

```
np.apply_along_axis(f, 2, a)
```

Note that `f()` will need to be changed:

```
def f(col):
    r, g, b = col
    return r, g, b, r + g + b
```